# Prove that if a set is Tarski-finite, then it is finite

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

A set $X$ is Tarski finite if any non-empty collection of subsets of $X$ has a minimal element (any element of the collection is not a proper subset of the minimal element). A set $X$ is finite if there is a bijection between a natural number and the set.

Suppose $X$ is Tarski-finite. Define the following relation $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathcal{X}$, where $\mathcal{X}$ is the set of collections of subsets of $X$:

$$f(i) = \begin{cases} \{X\}, & i=0 \\ f(i-1)\cup [L_{i-1}\backslash\{x_L\}] & i \neq 0 \ \land \ L_{i-1} \neq \varnothing \\ \varnothing &L_{i-1} = \varnothing \end{cases}$$

where $L_{i-1}$is the minimal element the collection $f(i-1)$ and $x_L$ is an element of $L_{n-1}$. We furthermore add the constraint that $f$ behave like a function, i.e., $\forall i \in \mathbb{N} \forall \mathcal X_1, \mathcal X_2 \in \mathcal X(\langle i,\mathcal X_1\rangle,\langle i,\mathcal X_2 \rangle \in f \implies \mathcal X_1=\mathcal X_2)$. Here's the behaviour of one such $f$ with $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$:
$$f(0) = \{\{a,b,c,d\}\}$$
$$f(1) = \{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,d\} \}$$
$$f(2) = \{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,d\}, \{a,b\} \}$$
$$f(3) = \{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,d\}, \{a,b\}, \{b\} \}$$
$$f(4) = \{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,d\}, \{a,b\}, \{b\}, \varnothing \}$$
$$f(5) = \varnothing$$

We now define $g: \mathbb{N} \to X$
$$g(i)=\begin{cases}x:x\in \cap f(0)\ \land \ x \notin \cap f(1) & i=0 \\ x:x \in \cap f(i) \ \land \ x \notin \cap f(i+1) & i \neq 0 \\ \varnothing & \cap f(i)=\varnothing \end{cases}$$

Whose behaviour is, taking as an example the above $f$:

$$g(0) = c$$
$$g(1) = d$$
$$g(2) = a$$
$$g(3) = b$$
$$g(4) = \varnothing$$

Which gives us our desired bijection with $4 = \{3,2,1,0\}$ if we restrict the domain of $g$, and we see how the same idea works with bigger T-finite sets.

**I have two questions on the above:** does the above proof properly establish the existence of the bijection? Second, it seems to me that it is somewhat contrived, but I couldn't manage to think of another way to do it. Is there a cleaner/faster way?

Thank you very much for any feedback!

Comment: I can't speak to your first question because I'm too lazy to read your proof. For your second question, is a proof by contradiction OK? Suppose $X$ is Tarski-finite but infinite (not finite). Then the collection of all infinite subsets of $X$ is nonempty, so it has a minimal element, call it $A$. Choose an element $a\in A$ and let $B=A\setminus\{a\}$. Then $B$ is finite, so $A=B\cup\{a\}$ is finite, a contradiction.

Comment: arghh that is so much faster, thanks a lot for the feedback

Comment: > does the above proof properly establish the existence of the bijection?

Not quite, because unless I am missing something you haven't prooved that f(n) will eventually be the empty set.

Comment: @Jsevillamol ohhhh right, thanks a lot for pointing that out! Very much appreciated!

Comment: Why is there a "the minimal"? What is "the" minimal in the collection of all singletons?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I might be very wrong, but: we can't get a collection of singletons, since we begin with $\{X\}$ and then obtain $\{X,X\backslash\{x\}\}$, and we always pick "a" minimal element from which we substract an element, guaranteeing the next minimal element is that one.

Comment: I don't see why you're not appealing to AC (or at least DC) in this argument. The whole point of the definition is that it holds in ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would be very interested to have your thoughts on that, the bijections definition requires AC, while T-finiteness does not? If you have time, I'd also be very interested in understanding how you would appeal to AC

Comment: @AsafKaragila To make a bit more clear why we can't have a list of singletons:
$$f(0) = \{X\}$$
$$f(1) = \{X, X\backslash \{x_1\}\}; x_1 \in X$$
$$f(2) = \{X, X\backslash \{x_1\}, [X\backslash\{x_1\}]\backslash \{x_2\}\}; x_2 \in X\backslash\{x_1\}$$, etc.

Comment: To see AC is not needed in general, look no further than the first comment you've received. To see where you've used AC, well, what is $x_1$? Why isn't it a different element of $X$? It could be, sure, but definitions need to be concrete, and you're using an arbitrary one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thank you very much for the help!